# BST getting path length of random nodes

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My goal is to select a random node from within my binary search tree and get its path length but I seem to be getting myself a little lost. I have a tree, it populates with random integers, I am able to see the length of each branch. But I'm not to sure how to select a random node and work out its path length. Any pointers in the right direction would be most helpful.

```
public static int[] generateRandomNumbers(int size) {
    if (size < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("size must be greater than less than 0");
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] results = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        results[i] = random.nextInt(size);
    }
    return results;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BST bst = new BST();
    int[] randoms = generateRandomNumbers(100);
    for (int i : randoms) {
        bst.insert(i);
    }
```

Above is the random number generator and how its implemented into the main. Including a pastebin of whole program in [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/TsSTTwgx) case you need more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which part is confusing: selecting a random node to look for or finding the path length to said randomly selected node?  Or both?

Comment: Well selecting the node has been solved so just returning its path length.

Comment: returning it path from? Root?

Comment: @SanketMakani Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate any `random_index` for the node in the range of `randoms` array and do other operations with it.

```
Random random = new Random();

int random_index= random.nextInt(randoms.length);

int random_node_data = randoms[random_index];

//Do other stuff with random_node
```

**EDIT :**

For finding path of a node from root, You can write store the track while finding the node in `StringBuilder` and return it when the required node is found. However here we are just finding a random node generated from existing nodes so there is no chance that the required node is not present in the `BST`.

```
static StringBuilder findPath (Node root , int data_to_be_found)
{
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

    if(root==null)
        return path;

    Node current_node = root;

    while(current_node != null)
    {
        if(path.size() > 0)
            path.append(" -> ");

        path.append(current_node.data);

        if(current_node.data == data_to_be_found)
            return path;

        if(data_to_be_found > current_node.data)
            current_node = current_node.right;
        else
            current_node = current_node.left;

    }

    return path;
}
```